# Exporting JAR file in Eclipse without method bodies

Tags: java, eclipse, api, jar, export

I'm working on a Java project using Eclipse where I'm responsible for creating an API for other people to use. I want to create a JAR file with my API, but I don't want other people to be able to decompile my source code so I'd like this exported file to contain only class structures (imagine I export my project, but I remove every method body and only leave their declarations, like in interfaces).

The idea is that there will be one application with the full API and other people will just upload their JAR files, which use my API, as plugins. Their JAR files will then be loaded by the app and any calls to my API will call the actual code in this app. This way other people don't need to have any information about contents of any method, just their signatures.

I know that one way to achieve this would be to create a separate project with public API interfaces only, and then implement these interfaces in the actual API project, but I'd like it to be the same project. Basically what I want is to export a full API to be used by my app and then export a stripped API with only public class/method signatures to be used by other people.

Is it possible to achieve such effect?

Edit:
I'd like to address a solution presented by rzwitserloot.

First of all, this solution is probably what one should follow to do it properly and I want to make it very clear I 100% agree with what was said there. I understand that what I want to do is not the most optimal solution, but I would really like to do it my way. I know what was suggested is way better, but I already have a project with tens of thousands of lines of code and I'm not keen on spending time on creating designated interfaces for the API. It's a small project I want to share with a few people, therefore just stripping the methods would be much easier and simpler for me. Once again, it's not a project meant for the public, but I don't want the source code to be accessible for others, but I want a few people to be able to add some functionality using my API.

Also, people using my API will be able to run their code at any moment as what they upload to my app will be immediately loaded and will be ready to be executed, so that's not the issue at all.

Answer (score 0):

> but I don't want other people to be able to decompile my source code

Ideas are a dime a dozen, decompiled java code is a maintenance nightmare, developers are hard to find, and software is almost always a living, breathing concept (it needs to be continually maintained and changed to deal with bugs, deal with updates/changes in external factors such as other libraries and web APIs, and feature requests). It's also legally shaky to use software without a license that covers this.

These 4 factors combine to make that concern silly. Stop worrying about it. If you have a useful project and wrote good code, they won't want to piss you off. It's nice to be needed, and all that.

But, if you insist on this silly course of action:

> The idea is that there will be one application with the full API and other people will just upload their JAR files, which use my API, as plugins.

"Strip my code out" is not how you solve this problem.

Make an actual API. Just interfaces or very bare-bones classes. Then, your library (with the actual intelligent code bits in it) are implementations of it.

For example:

```
# mythingie-api.jar, contains:

# com/foo/yourthingie/ImageDecoder.class, compiled from:
public interface ImageDecoder {
    Image decode(byte[] data);
    String getMimeType();
    List<String> getCommonFileExtensions();
}

# com/foo/yourthingie/ImageDecoding.class, compiled from:
public class ImageDecoding {
    private static final List<ImageDecoder> decoders = findDecoders();

    public static ImageDecoder forMime(String mime) {
        for (var d : decoders) if (d.getMimeType().equals(mime)) return d;
        throw new NoSuchOperationException("No image decoder for: " + mime);
    }

    private static List<ImageDecoder> findDecoders() {
        return ServiceLoader.load(ImageDecoder.class).stream().toList();
    }
}
```

and that's all that's in there. You ship this, and the source. Then you also have:

```
# mythingie-impl.jar, contains:

# META-INF/services/com.foo.yourthingie.ImageDecoder, containing:
com.foo.yourthingie.impl.JpgDecoder
com.foo.yourthingie.impl.PngDecoder

# com/foo/yourthingie/JpgDecoder, compiled from:

public class JpgDecoder implements ImageDecoder {
    @Override public String getMimeType() {
        return "image/jpeg";
    }

    .. etcetera
}

# com/foo/yourthingie/PngDecoder, compiled from:

public class PngDecoder implements ImageDecoder {
    @Override public String getMimeType() {
        return "image/png";
    }

    .. etcetera
}
```

Of course, if you don't ship that `impl`, then users of your framework can't actually run their code, and thus whatever they'd write, is likely an inefficiently set up, bug-riddled mess. Just ship it. But if you must, here you go. Now you know how to do it.

Comment: Thank you very much for that. After reading that I think I should address something.

I will edit my post as there is not enough space to write it here. Please take a look, if possible.

Comment: Generally if you ask: "Are there easy ways to do this _established crazy way of working no sane person would ever do_", the answer is regrettably: "No". Why would one write a framework to support an exotic way of working that has virtually zero use cases, after all? You can get java parsers and rewrite your code. These tools are extremely complicated. javac is GPL without classpath exception, so you can't use it unless you foss the entire thing, and ecj is fast, MIT-licensed, but very had to understand and use. What you describe would take weeks to months.